Multi Level Mixed Models
I have a model in which I collected information from 3 different farms, and on each farm in several different weeks. The weeks are not exactly the same, so week 1 of Farm 1 is not the same moment as week 1 of Farm 2. It is always sampling new elements within the week.
I applied the following syntax:
glmer(PCR ~ Sample + (1 | Farm/WEEK) , family = binomial(link="logit"),  
            data=data)

I'm not sure how to insert the random component. Because I want to know what the probability of PCR being positive from a type of sample.
And I need to control for the effect of the week within the farm - so that the model has a sample related result.

Hi, how many weeks do you have? What kind of variable is "Sample"?

With only 3 farms, a random effect model such as this is highly suspect. I would instead use a so-called fixed effects model in which you include 0/1 indicators for each farm (minus one) and perhaps for week. Using glm, this model would be as follows,
m1 <-glm(PCR ~ Sample + as.factor(Farm)*as.factor(WEEK), 
        family = binomial(link="logit"), data=data)

This model allows for each farm to have a unique intercept, for there to be a unique week intercept, and for there to be a week by farm interaction such that each farm can have its own unique week effect. Now, this model will not work unless Sample varies within farms. If Sample does not vary within farms, then you would likely have to go back to a random effects model, but given the sample size, would need to use a Bayesian approach (see this example) with informative priors on the random effects.
